# How to make overfitting (powerful) model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

According to my professor one of the first steps in modelling a NN is to use a powerful enough model.

> The first step is to create a model that is powerful enough to 
>   achieve very high accuracies (very low loss) on the training data, at
>   least when no regularisation is used.

What are some of the things (obviously apart of regulazing and adjusting learning rate), that I can do to make my model "powerful" enough, in other words to let it overfit on the training data?

Am I looking in the right direction with the following things?

1. Add extra layers
2. Make layers thicker (more neurons)

Comment: If you are aiming to overfit, (I assume with the intention to then reduce this later) you should look to create a more 'complex' model. i.e. more flexible i.e. more parameters. This means no regularization / dropout. No early stopping. More layers and more nodes.

Comment: Yes the intention is to reduce the overfitting later using regularization, early stopping, ... But the first step should be to have a complex/powerful enough model that is able to overfit on the training data. The professor indicated that when plotting the Accuracy (Y-axis) vs the epochs (X-axis), the accuracy should quickly go to 1. Apart from how this is done, do you have any explanation on why? And could I play around with the learning rate for this, or should I also stay away from this (like the regularization)?

Comment: Overfitting means modelling noise. The more parameters your model has, the more flexibly it can learn each point of noise. Think about a linear model, it can't go through each noisy point so it will struggle to overfit noisy data. But if you have a polynomial model, for each new polynomial term you add (i.e. a new model parameter to learn), you give it more flexibility to bend to fit each point. In a NN, the weights are the parameters, adding more nodes means more weights mean it can model more noise.

Comment: Can I assume that to overfit, the amount of parameters it thus important? The way you get this is less important (thicker or deeper network)?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some general hyperparameter adjustments to increase model capacity:

1. Architecture-related:

   - add additional layers
   - increase the number of hidden units per layer
   - remove dropout or decrease dropout rates
2. Optimizer related:

   - find the optimal learning rate
   - train for more epochs

[Section 11.4.1](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/guidelines.html) in the Deep Learning Book provides a good overview. The paper ["Practical recommendations for gradient-based training of deep architectures"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533.pdf) is another good source to understand the effect of different hyperparameters (though it is a bit older).

Moreover, there are specific hyperparameters to increase model capacity for different network types, e.g.

- kernel size for CNNs,
- sequence length for LSTMs and
- embedding dimension for embedding layers.