# Use of multiple models vs training a single model for multiple outputs

Tags: machine-learning-model, theory

So let's say I have data with numerical variables `A`, `B` and `C`.

I believe that the value of `A` has an effect on `B`.
I also believe that `A` and `B` both have an effect on `C`.
I don't think `C` has an effect on either `A` or `B`.

I want to use machine learning to predict `A`, `B`, and `C`. I obviously have `A` and `B` as training data, and I have other variables as training data too.

Do I simply create multiple models to predict all three, or is there a way to make one model predict them all if I just throw the entire dataset at it?

Comment: Kindly post a sample of your data.

Comment: "I want to use machine learning to predict `A`, `B`, and `C`. I obviously have `A` and `B` as training data."

I don't understand this statement. Why do you want to predict `A` and `B` if you already have this information? I don't understand what do you want to predict, and which variables are you going to use to predict, ie: which are your features and which is your target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a data sample to answer better to your question?

For instance, are those variables related to time?

If yes, time series based models could be interesting like multi LSTM:
[LSTM Multi-class classification for large number of classes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68725/lstm-multi-class-classification-for-large-number-of-classes)

If not, you could use a random forest regressor.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html

My best advice is to start with a simple single model that makes predictions on A, B and C, and then try more complex ones.

Comment: If you consider the answer somewhat usefull, don't hesitate to upvote it as acknowledgment :)